# Identity Server 4 + Angular SPA as Federation Gateway for external providers

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm designing the system with next components:
 - Angular SPA
 - .NET Core microservices (one of them in AuthService)

I want to implement the architecture, where my IS4 will act as federation gateway (as client for external providers - Facebook, Microsoft, Google etc). And at the same time it must act as a provider for angular SPA (which will act a as client).

So I want implement the next flow.
 - User clicks to social network login button (from the SPA)
 - IS4 is called and acts as a client for external provides
 - User finished the auth, external token received by IS4
 - ???
 - SPA client gets the internal tokens

So the main stuck is how to implement the exchange token from external provider to internal one.
 - For this case how SPA should be setuped?
 - How integration between IS4 and SPA after receiving the external token should be done?
 - What parameters should be in the request from SPA in this case?
 - Could we use IS4 token endpoint and do internal token issuing by the internals of IS4?

Comment: There is a tutorial on how to set the SP4 as a Federation Gateway for external providers. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/federation_gateway.html. Is your scenario out of the scope of the documentation?

Comment: I researched through the docs, articles, questions on the SO and a lot of available examples and hadn't found the information.

The given article described the general concept of this architecture. But the scope of my question is the correct flow (how SPA must be registered) and tokens exchange in this flow (I could do the generation of token by myself and return it to the client in the query param, but don't this that it is the correct and secure way)

Comment: The default scenario for IS4 is to return whatever token is received from the external providers to be used by the client (your SPA). But you can definitely create an internal token and use it around the microservices. The other thing is you can pass your token in a JSON request/response body instead of the query params and use HTTPS for connections.

Comment: @Ghukas it partially sounds strange for me, cause if I will return tokens from different external providers, I will need to set the validation params for every provider in my microservices (for example, if we do this validation in the services). And when a new provider will appear, the all microservices must be updated. Is it sounds a little strange?
I know about grant exchange (but for this case, the whole external providers should be invoked from the SPA and tokens must be exhanged on my back). But it's not a federation gateway way. Thank you for your concerns and time

Comment: (1/2) Hmm, what I was thinking is all the external providers are added to the IS4 and, therefore, do the validation in the IS4. If there is a need to add another external provider in the future, you'll need to add the service config and have the validation done in some `ExternalProviderValidator` you can create.

Comment: (2/2) In other words, the services should not care about the origin of the token that comes with the requests, they just need to get the tokens verified.

Comment: @Myte perhaps the "adding a JavaScript client" tutorial will help - https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html ... also there is a Pluralsight course I found useful (although may not exactly answer your question, but helped me better understand the IdentityServer communication with third-party providers like Facebook etc - https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/authentication-authorization-aspnet-core/table-of-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've got the solution to my little concept mess.

The architecture is:
 - Angular SPA - **Client**
 - IS4 Backend + SPA with interactions, served by the same service (instead of Quickstart UI) - **Identity Service**

The flow is next:
 - Client starts PKCE flow
 - Interactions SPA (with external login provider login buttons, log/pass fields etc) is displayed for user (loaded from Identity service)
 - User clicks external provider button and interaction starts between user and external provider
 - After interaction ends, IS4 redirects to the Client with Code
 - Client requests for the token with this code (finishes the PKCE flow)

So the main missconcept was with the responsibility. All UI, related to authorization must be in the IS4 side.